# Using wget with subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to use wget with `subprocess`.

my attempts worked until I tried to download the page to a specified directory with this code:

```
url = 'google.com'
location = '/home/patrick/downloads'
args = ['wget', 'r', 'l 1' 'p' 'P %s' % location, url]

output = Popen(args, stdout=PIPE)
```

if I run this code in `/home/patrick` I get `index.html` in `/home/patrick` and not in `/home/patrick/downloads`.

Can you help me?

Thanks ;)

Comment: why not use urllib or httplib?

Comment: The main reason I see not to use a python library is if you're getting large files you don't have to use interpreter memory to download & process them - you just hand it off to another process built to do that part, all unix like.

Comment: I needed a command to download a whole webpage :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have hyphens and `location` should be just another argument:

```
args = ['wget', '-r', '-l', '1', '-p', '-P', location, url]
```

Comment: And some spaces? All of those single-quoted strings are goign to get mashed together without spaces between them.

Comment: Now that there are commas between them, I think that it would work. In the code that Patrick posted, the ones without commas, to make them separate elements of the array, all gget concatenated together. You are doing it correctly in your answer, SilentGhost.

Comment: Yeah! Thanks! It works :D I just forgot some commas after 'l 1' and 'p' ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** `popen` from `os` intends to [replace](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) `os.popen` module. Hence, using `os.popen` is not recommended

Initially I thought it was `popen` from `os`.

If you are using `popen` from `os`

```
#wget 'http://google.com/' -r -l 1 -p -P /Users/abhinay/Downloads

from os import popen

url = 'google.com'
location = '/Users/abhinay/Downloads'
args = ['wget %s', '-r', '-l 1', '-p', '-P %s' % location, url]

output = popen(' '.join(args))
```

and using `Popen` from `subprocess`

```
#wget 'http://google.com/' -r -l 1 -p -P Downloads/google

from subprocess import Popen

url = 'google.com'
location = '/Users/abhinay/Downloads'
#as suggested by @SilentGhost the `location` and `url` should be separate argument
args = ['wget', '-r', '-l', '1', '-p', '-P', location, url]

output = Popen(args, stdout=PIPE)
```

Let me know if I'm missing something.

Thx!

Comment: docs say: *args* should be a string, or a sequence of program arguments.

Comment: subprocess.Popen should be used instead of os.popen

Comment: @SilentGhost Initially I thought it was popen from os, I edited my answer now.



@Corey Thanks for the suggestion! looks like `popen` is an older and replaced by `Popen`.

Comment: gosh, I I couldn't even imagine that you'd be advising `os.open`, it indeed required a string as a first argument.